# generalize state machine in Verilog for N bit

Tags: embedded, verilog

If I have a three bit simple state machine there will be a total of 8 states. The code in Verilog is here:

```
 module state_machine( input clk , input reset );    
 `define s0     3'b 000
 `define s1     3'b 001
 `define s2     3'b 010
 `define s3     3'b 011
 `define s4     3'b 100
 `define s5     3'b 101
 `define s6     3'b 110
 `define s7     3'b 111
 reg [2:0] state;
initial 
state = {$random%3};

 always @(posedge clk) begin 
 if (reset==0)
        state= `s0; 
    else
          case  (state)        
                `s0:   state =`s1 ;                 
                `s1:   state =`s2 ;                 
                `s2:   state =`s3 ;                 
                `s3:   state =`s4 ;                 
                `s4:   state =`s5 ;                 
                `s5:   state =`s6 ;             
                `s6:   state =`s7 ;
                `s7:   state ={$random%3} ;
             default:   state =`s0   
           endcase
 end
endmodule
```

But now I want to make a simple state machine for N number of bits with (2^N) states. it mean now we have only 3 bits so there are (2^3)=8 state. so for N bit we will have 2^N bit.

How i can make it. please, i really want your help.

[image]

Comment: Note how each states decimal value is the previous + 1, so you could just have `state <= state + 1;`

Comment: For flip-flops (`always@(posedge clk ...`) use non-blocking ( `<=`) assignmnets

Comment: It looks to me that you almost want to build a counter, but instead of wrapping to zero, it wraps to a random number.

Comment: Yes sir @Marty.. I want a countr start with random numbr and go to each state. But the countr may be for n numbr of bits

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should implement this as a counter with a load function. When your load signal is asserted, you load your input (which for your case can be assigned a random value). After that it operates as a normal counter. You can create an n-bit counter using a parameter for the counter width.

Then you can use a bit-wise "&" reduction operator to check when the count value is all '1's and ready to roll over, and use that to trigger the load.